# Error al conectar aplicación en Java/JSP con base de datos (Mysql) alojada en 000WebHost

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Cordial saludo equipo espero se encuentren bien, necesito pedirles el favor con el siguiente inconveniente:

Tengo una aplicación en Java-Jsp que deseo conectar con Mysql, En principio me generaba un error que tenia que ver con la versión del driver, para ello actualice un driver que teniay lo modifique por el (mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar).
, y modifique dentro del código lo siguiente:

```
  String driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
```

pero   al correr el aplicativo me muestra el siguiente error:

> Error al conectar la BDjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: driver
> driver

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

El código del archivo Conexión.java, es el siguiente:

```
package Control;

import java.sql.*;

public class Conexion {
  ////  String driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
   public static Connection getConnection(){
      String driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
       String url, userName, password;
      // url = "jdbc:mysql:localhost/alumnotas";
      // userName ="root";
     //  password ="";
   
       Connection con=null;
       try{
          Class.forName("driver");
        
            con=DriverManager.getConnection        ("jdbc:mysql://localhost/alumnotas?user=jdbc:mysql:localhost:3306/id19610817_alumnotas?user=root&password=");
         System.out.println("Conexion Exitosa con la BD");
       }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println("Error al conectar la BD" + e);
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
   
   return con;
    }
       public static void main(String[] args){
         Conexion.getConnection();
       }
}
```

En internet no veo ninguna solución a dicho inconveniente, agradezco la colaboración que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 0):

```
package Control;

import java.sql.*;

public class Conexion {

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";

        //INGRESE BIEN EL URL (REEMPLACE EL PUERTO POR EL SUYO Y EL NOMBRE DE LA BASE DE DATOS)
        //ESTRUCTURA (jdbc:mysql://localhost:PUERTO/?user=root)

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alumnotas", userName = "root", password = "";
        Connection con = null;

        try {
            //Descomentar driver
            Class.forName(driver);

            //Hacemos uso de la url, userName y password de arriba
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            System.out.println("Conexion Exitosa con la BD");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error al conectar la BD" + e);
        }

        return con;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Conexion.getConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Modifique un poquito tu codigo, pero creo que el problema estaba en la url (asegurece de poner bien su puerto y el nombre de la base de datos) y el Class.ForName("drive") por la comillas del drive (leer los comentarios del codigo).

Comment: Hola gracias por la ayuda, realice los cambios solicitados en los comentarios del códigos pero sigue mostrandome el mismo inconveniente
el error que dice: "Error al conectar la BDjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: driver", vale mencionar que inclui dentro de la cadena de conexion
las credenciales que me proporciona el 000WebHost, es decir :
Nombre de la Base de Datos: id19610817_alumnotas
Usuario de la Base de Datos: id19610817_root
Host de la Base de datos: localhost

no se a que se deba el inconveniente, Gracias!.